# I need to validate my calender so it only accepts current or future dates?

Tags: javascript, function, date

Hi i am trying to write a JavaScript function to only allow future or on the day selection, using a calender.

I am getting quite confused. I want to compare the input from the user to the current date then pass back a true or false return, this then will bring up a error message.

Here is my if statement code:

```
if (this.element.find('#visitdate').length > 0)
{
    var check = this.element.find('#visitdate');
    var today = new Date().getTime();

    if (!check.text(today??) < 0)
    {
        _errMsg = "Please enter a future date";
        return false;
    }
    else 
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Can anyone lead me in the correct direction.

Answer (score 1):

If you use jquery ui, you can set the parameter `minDate`, so only future dates and current day will be allowed:

```
$(function() {
$( "#visitdate" ).datepicker({ minDate: 0 });
});
```

Example : http://jsfiddle.net/lparcerisa/Lwpyr09k/2/

**Edit**: in case you're not allowed to do so, you could check the date like this (if you're expecting standard input):

```
var check = Date.parse($('#visitdate').val());
var today = new Date().getTime(); 
if (check < today) { ... }
```

or this, e.g. to use dates d/m/Y :

```
var dateParts = $('#visitdate').val().split('/');
var check = new Date(dateParts[2], dateParts[1], dateParts[0], 0,0,0,0).getTime();
var today = new Date().getTime(); 
if (check < today) { ... }
```

Fiddle first option: http://jsfiddle.net/lparcerisa/pr0b0n6z/

Fiddle second option: http://jsfiddle.net/lparcerisa/phnvvza3/1/

Comment: I am editing a pre-built form which is generated, the calender is already made so this doesnt work on mine. Thanks anyway

Comment: I've edited the answer, let's see if this is useful for your project :)

Comment: Brilliant.. the 2nd one allows you to do dd/mm/yy even on google chrome as i know they bloody validate it US style automatically?

Answer (score 0):

Filter the text value like this:

```
if (!check.text() == today)
```

Comment: doesn't seem to do the job still?

Comment: are you doing check for < 0 ??

Comment: Please try that once.

Comment: if (!check.text() == today).length < 0 (like this)